# Mobile Safari: Authentication Data Lost On Img Request

Tags: authentication, mobile-safari, image, 3g

A very, VERY disappointing behavior took me literally hours to realise:
Mobile Safari (on iPad and iPhone) **doesn't send the authentication headers ("Cookie" entry in Http-headers) in an *image* request** - ***IF*** and only if the request is done via **3G/Edge network** - in **Wifi-mode it works**!?! - Bump

All that Mobile Safari showed me was a white question mark in a blue box.

BUT if I did a XHttpRequest, I got the data. If I inserted an image tag dynamically via JavaScript the image got loaded.

- **regular** image-data requests have **no** authentication information
- **dynamic** image-data requests ***have*** authentication information

Background:
I'm developing an Asp MVC 3 WebApp which has a image handler. This image handler has a check if the request is authenticated and if not, it returns an empty result:

```
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    return new EmptyResult();
```

Questions:

- Did anybody experience the same issue?
- Did anybody found a reliable
  workaround?

Thanks,
Lg warappa

Edit:
Added info that http-header "Cookie" is used for authentication.